# Is there a need to specify javascript and ccs references in linked pages?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a lot of html pages that always start with the same  section, for example in index.html I have

```
<head>
<title>Conference Room Booking App - Welcome</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="css/themes/1/conf-room1.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/themes/1/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../../lib/jqm/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="../../lib/jquery/2.1.3/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../lib/jqm/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script></head>
```

Other pages are linked from this page, for example

```
 <a href="sign-up.html" class="ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-corner-all">Sign Up</a>
```

Currently I have the same header in each of the linked pages.  As an experiment I removed the references to the css and js files from the head section of the linked page, leaving just the title, for example

```
<head>
<title>Conference Room Booking App - Sign In</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></head>
```

And the page still worked, the formatting and scripts from the css and js files from the index page were used in the linked page.

Will this always work?  Is this valid HTML5?  I understand that if a browser references the linked page directly that would not work.

Comment: I don't believe you ;) A new page, will _not_ load any assets from a previous page. And it shouldn't. As a browser cannot decide for you which of the assets you used on a previous page will be needed on the next page as well. Anyway, it is not nearly valid HTML5 and that it works for you sounds like mere luck or like a bug. Which browser are you using anyway? Can you show us a working example?

Comment: I'm guessing the browser cached the previous version. If you clear the cache, I bet the resources will not be loaded.

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple way of know where the .js and the .css flies come from.

1. If the links page are inside a master page or other page, there should be your header links.
2. If the link page is placed isn't nested you can check the following steps to figure where links came from.

   - Open your site in IE10+
   - Press 12 to open the developers tools.
   - go to Network tab, press play button.
   - reload the page to watch all the request your browse make.
   - select the ones you want and go to Details view.
   - finally check in the Initiator link who fires the request.

You can alway try Ctrol + F5 to force the browser to delete cache and reload all the resources again (just in case).

Answer (score 1):

If you load pages via AJAX it may work but if you load each page separately you need to include all css&javascript files page need.

Perhaps it is cached in browser (try reload with Ctrl+R or Ctrl+F5) so it loads css etc. from cache and that is why it looks like those files are not needed.

BTW consider merging css into one file so you can save loading time.
See https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/ for instructions.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a PHP file containing the contents you want to put in your `<head>`

For instance, you can create a file called header.php, and put all the code you want to use in other HTML files in it.

Then from your other HTML files, you can access it by simply including it:

```
<?php include '/yourfolder/header.php'; ?>
```